# Android SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter Section Header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I am using SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter from [luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) as adapter for my RecyclerView.

We can add `Section` to `SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter` with `Header` layout, as below:

```
public class Section1 extends Section {
    public Section1 () {
        super(
                R.layout.section_1_header,
                R.layout.section_1_item,
                R.layout.section_1_loading,
                R.layout.section_1_failed
        );
    }

    .....
}


.....


Section1 section1 = new Section1();
section1.setState(Section.State.LOADING);

SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();
sectionAdapter.addSection(section1);

recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

During `loading` state, I am showing a spinning progress bar as defined in `section_1_loading.xml`. But my problem is the `header` is already shown when section is still in `loading state`. How do I hide header before state changes to `loaded`?

I thought about only add `header` to Section after state changes to `loaded`. But seems can't as only way to set Section's header is in Section's constructor.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks!

Comment: please attach snapshot if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to override the [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/library/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.java) class and in `onBindViewHolder` replace

`if (section.hasHeader())`

by

`if (section.hasHeader() && section.getState() != Section.State.LOADING)`

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I managed to make it work with my code below, thanks again! :D

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work now, with hints above from Alexandre. The workaround is:

```
// loading state - set no header so header section is hidden
section1.setHasHeader(false);
section1.setState(Section.State.LOADING);

....
....

// loaded state - set has header so header section is shown
section1.setHasHeader(true);
section1.setState(Section.State.LOADED);
```

Thanks!